# How to access a cookieStore from other classes?

Tags: java, android, cookies, session-cookies, cookiestore

So I'm working on an app where I'm trying to store a cookie from a log in screen then access that cookie in another class.

How can I access the cookie store in the first class in the second class so I can access that cookie? Also, do I need to keep the cookie in cookie store? Or can I just store the `.getValue` in a string and use that in the other class? because I tried the second option but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you building your own webapp framework, or are you using an existing one like JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Java Web Application? If so don't use cookies, use the HttpSession to store all session data.

Comment: Sorry, haven't done much Android programming so I am not sure how cookies are relevant outside a browser.